# Reading Registry Keys to Check 32/64-bit Application

Tags: special-characters, nsis

I want to read out my application name via NSIS from the windows registry. 
The application name may be "Application (x86)" or "Application (x64)"
I'm using following code:

```
ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Something\Something\" "ApplicationName"
```

The output of the value of `$R1` is always **"Application"** without the brackets.
Does `ReadRegStr` always ignore special characters?
Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadRegStr does not filter the string in any way:

```
Section
; Write the test string first
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\NSIS\Test\" "Application" "Application (x86)"

; ...and then read it and display the result
ReadRegStr $R1 HKCU "Software\NSIS\Test\" "Application" 
MessageBox MB_OK "$R1"

; Cleanup
DeleteRegKey HKCU "Software\NSIS\Test\"
SectionEnd
```

Is it possible that you are reading an old string in the wrong place in the registry caused by registry redirection/reflection or 32 vs 64-bit views?

Monitor the installer with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) so you can see the actual place in the registry you are reading from and the value returned to the application.

Comment: Problem were the 32/64-bit views. Solved it by using "SetRegView 32" and "SetRegView 64".